# textbox validation accepting Ports in javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox

the question was accepting one or many ports that has one space between them with help of friends,
I used this one for my answer but for example if I enter 88888 it will alert me such this thing:
88888NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN is not correct

how can I correct this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function portvalidating(field)
{
    var output='';
    m=field.value;
    if(/^\d{1,5}([ ]\d{1,5})*$/.test(m))
    {
        var parts = m.split(' ');
        for(i in parts)
        {
            var p= parseInt(parts[i]);
            if(!((0 <= p) && (p<= 65535) && !isNaN(p)))
            {
                output+=p;
            }
        }
        if(output=='')
            var dummy=1;
        else alert(output+'is not correct');
    }
    else alert('please enter a valid port!');
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking it is bad form on SO to edit your question such that no answers make sense. In this case, you have put your final solution up in place of your original question. Also, it is helpful to others to accept an answer when your question has been answered. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, regular expressions can't handle 'ranges', so you can't do this exactly as you want with regexp (therorically you can, but the regex would be hiper,hiper long).

However, you could validate your space-separated numbers with this regexp:

```
/^\d{1,5}([ ]\d{1,5})*$/
```

This will do what you want, except validating the range you supplied. But it controls that numbers have between 1 and 5 digits, and the other things you asked.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: thanks,would you please explain it more? what is *$ and [ ] you mean space?

Answer (score 1):

A crude regex without much error checking would be: `exp = /\d{1,5}/g` and then call `.match(exp)` on your string. However, you will need to use parseInt to convert the output to a number so that you can check it's value against your constraints.

I think you may be able to do this easier without Regex. Some quick code to split and parse a string is:

```
var s = "21 456 -32 70000";
var parts = s.split(' ');
var output;
for(i in parts)
{
  p = parseInt(parts[i]);
  if( (0 <= p) && (p <= 65535) && !isNaN(p) )
    output += p+"<br />";
}
```

Hopefully this helps to some degree.

Comment: with vars you mean a test ha?

Comment: I tried yours but no result I added alert(output) but it shows me nothing maybe I'm not right can you put your code with a function?

Comment: I got it! :) thanks,you had some errors in your code like"<br/>" no need to=>" but I used yours,and Edgar

Comment: I left out some pieces as I wasn't sure how you wanted to display the output.  Glad it is working for you!

Comment: thank you Manocho,see up there I used yours,it has a small problem

Comment: Hmm, that's odd...it sounds like a browser issue. Your code works for me in Firefox 5.0.  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|\d{2,4}|[1-9])
```

Comment: thanks,I understood the range but I didn't understand where you put space?

Comment: no spaces. here's an example in Javascript "123 60 34".match(/(6553[0-5]|655[0-2][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|\d{2,4}|[1-9])/g) It will output ["123", "60", "34"]

Comment: also, you can have something like this: var x = "80 21 test 88888".split(" "); console.log(x.map(function(item, idx, arr){ if (parseInt(item) < 65535) { return item; } return arr; })); will output [80, 21] only

Answer (score 0):

I think you would compromise your performance here if you want you are trying to validate a simple Integer value via RegEx.

IMO, try spiting the string with Space `(' ')` and and convert each value to Integer and perform `myInt < 65535`.

```
for( String str : portNumbers.split(' ') ){
  try{
    int i = Integer.parseInteger( str );
    if( 0 > i && i > 65535 ){
      errorMessage = str + " is out of range.";
    }
  }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    errorMessage = str + " is not a valid port.";
  }
}
```