# Reject some number-strings that parseInt accepts?

Tags: javascript

the question was accepting one or many ports that has one space between them

with help of friends
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593500/textbox-validation-accepting-ports-in-javascript), I used this one for my answer
but for example if I enter 88888 it will alert me such this thing:

```
88888NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN is not correct
```

how can I correct this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function portvalidating(field)
    {
    var output='';
        m=field.value;
        if(/^\d{1,5}([ ]\d{1,5})*$/.test(m))
        {
        var parts = m.split(' ');
        for(i in parts)
        {
          var p= parseInt(parts[i]);
        if(!((0 <= p) && (p<= 65535) && !isNaN(p)))
        {
        output+=p;
        }
        }
    if(output=='')
        var dummy=1;
        else alert(output+'is not correct');
        }
        else alert('please enter a valid port!');
        }
```

Comment: For a question such as this, consider listing *multiple* examples of "good data" and "bad data". (This particular check can be done somewhat trivially with a simple regular expression without a range check: it takes a little more to get the range checking.)

Comment: thank you,sorry I didn't understand that now I must do what

Comment: I think this checking is working but I can't get the 88888 cause it is 88888Nan usually vars by going to parseint has value NaNNaN....(not a number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating your concerns of reading/writing to form data from input validation from alerting.  Here is a hint on the function to validate a string of space separated integers in [0..65535]:

```js
var getPorts = function(str) {
  var ns=(""+str).split(/\s+/), ports=[], n, i;
  for (i=0; i<ns.length; i++) {
    n = parseInt(ns[i], 10);
    if (isFinite(n) && !isNaN(n)
          && (ns[i]==n) // Make sure the number is an integer.
          && (n >= 0) && (n <= 65535)) {
      ports.push(n);
    }
  }
  return ports;
};

getPorts('-1 0 NaN 123 foo 255 99999'); // => [0, 123, 255]
```

Comment: Wow. Very clever use of `ns[i] == n` -- missed it the first go-about. It deserves some special mention.

Comment: Never forget to pass the radix to `parseInt`, should be `10` in this case. Maybe I'm missing something, but what do you use `ns[i]==n` for?

Comment: Note: `getPorts('-1 08 09 NaN 123 foo 255 99999');` would return `[123, 255]` here. Better use `Number(ns[i])` or `parseInt(ns[i],10)`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here my "answer". It is very close to the code posted, but there are differences as noted. Complete with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhZ6g/5/) post.

```
// Returns: {ports, invalid}
// where ports are valid ports and invalid are ... not valid items.
function getPorts (inp) {
    var invalid = [];
    var ports = [];
    // The /\s+/ ensures that multiple whitespace is skipped.
    var split = inp.split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        var str = split[i];
        // It is generally best to *always* specify a base.
        // (Otherwise it might be treated as hex or octal, which may or
        // may not be okay. Adjust as required.)
        var val = parseInt(str, 10);
        // Need to make sure we have all digits.
        // This is because parseInt("1foo2", 10) evaluates to 1
        // and parseInt("8888NaN") evaluates to 8888
        if (!str.test(/^\d+$/) || !(val >= 0 && val <= 0xffff)) {
            invalid.push(str);
        } else {
            ports.push(val);
        }
    }
    return {ports: ports, invalid: invalid};
}

// if r.invalid.length > 0 then it contained some "invalid" items.
// it may also be "invalid" if r.ports.length == 0

var r = getPorts("88888NaNNaN");
alert("ports: " + r.ports);
alert("invalid: " + r.invalid);

var r = getPorts("123 12345 88888 NaN NaN 1d234");
alert("ports: " + r.ports);
alert("invalid: " + r.invalid);
```

Happy coding.

---

Please put this in a function, as per maerics's post.